# Reactv2.20.2 with typescript not able to render component with <Navigate to ="/login'/>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

```
import { createBrowserRouter, createRoutesFromElements, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import ErrorBoundary from './ErrorBoundary'; // Import your ErrorBoundary component
import Login from './Login'; // Import your Login component
import Home from './Home'; // Import your Home component
import Protected from './Protected'; // Import your Protected component

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route errorElement={<ErrorBoundary />}>
      <Route element={<Protected />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
    </Route>
  )
);

export default router;


import { FunctionComponent } from 'react';
import { Navigate, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

interface ProtectedProps {}

const Protected: FunctionComponent<ProtectedProps> = () => {
  const authenticated = false; // 

  if (!authenticated) { 
//  navigate to the login page here it not rendering the login component ? why so
 but it is rendering with <outlet> Note here I want to render only login not all the routes only login how to achieve that ? 
    return <Navigate to="/login" />;
  }

  
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Protected Content</h1>
      {/* Add your protected content components here */}
    </>
  );
};

export default Protected;
```

if (!authenticated) {
// If not authenticated, navigate to the login page. here it is not rendering the login component ? but it is rendering with <outlet> even if we hit with other route from the browser it should replace with login path and render login component
return <Navigate to="/login" />;
}? Note : only render login page but others routes when i use <outlet> it is rendering all routes hit from browser even if i get any route just replace with login and render the only login component ?

Comment: Is the `Protected` component supposed to wrap your other routes and actually render an `Outlet`?

Comment: Protected component should be warped  other routes and the render login component  if it is not authenticated so..

Answer (score 0):

As-is your `Protected` route component needs a path since it isn't a layout route (*not rendering nested routes and an `Outlet`*). Making it the home `"/"` or index route seems to allow it to function as you are expecting. When the app loads and the URL path is `"/"` the `Protected` route component is rendered and the auth check occurs.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route errorElement={<ErrorBoundary />}>
      <Route index element={<Protected />} /> // rendered on "/"
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
    </Route>
  )
);
```

If you meant for `Protected` component to be a layout route component then it should render an `Outlet` and actually wrap the routes it protects.

Example:

```
const Protected = () => {
  const authenticated = false; // 

  return authenticated
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
};
```

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route errorElement={<ErrorBoundary />}>
      <Route element={<Protected />}>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  )
);
```

Note that with this implementation you'll likely also have an error/warning about a missing route on `"/"`.

Comment: const Protected = () => {
  const authenticated = false; // 

  return authenticated
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
}; how to make this an funtional component?

Comment: @AshokReddy It already is a React function component. It's certainly not a React class component.

Comment: Suppose if i hit /home path in browser then it is not checking for Protected .directly rendering home without protected check? how check ?

Comment: @AshokReddy That depends on your authentication logic, but a `useEffect` hook could be used to issue a side-effect to check the user's access. I assumed you already handled correctly computing your `authenticated` value.

Comment: How to protect all child routes of it <Route index element={<Protected />} /> // rendered on "/"?

Comment: Can you guide me ,How to protect all child routes of it <Route index element={<Protected />} /> // rendered on "/"?

Comment: @AshokReddy Are you now basically asking [How to create a protected route](/a/66289280/8690857)?

Comment: const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route errorElement={<ErrorBoundary />}>
      <Route index element={<Protected />} /> // rendered on "/"
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
    </Route>
  )
);  as per suggestion , How can we have protected check for path Home as well..etc ..

Comment: @AshokReddy Oh, I see what you are asking now. See the second half of my answer using a layout route to wrap the routes you want to protect.

Comment: can you please give with sample example i was bit confused ?above solution

Comment: const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route errorElement={<ErrorBoundary />}>
      <Route index element={<Protected />} /> // rendered on "/"
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
    </Route>
  )
); i see above sample suggested code by you ,here how i can wrap the child routes to protected because  <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} /> placed out side of <Route index element={<Protected />} /> // rendered on "/" ?

Comment: – Drew Reese? any idea for above comment ?

Comment: @AshokReddy I provided two router configuration examples. Check the second example where both `"/login"` and `"/home"` are nested under the protected route.